# Parsing deeply nested object from HTTP API call with Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am calling the Singapore government's public `taxi-availability` API and am trying to get the value of the `coordinates` array which is a list of objects. However, I am having difficulty parsing the response as it is a deeply nested object and I do not want to define a separate data class for it

Response data model (not all keys are shown):

```js
{
    features: [
        {
            geometry: {
                coordinates: [
                    {

                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Code to get the response:

```java
String uri = "https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/taxi-availability";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
```

Code to convert the response from string to an object:

```java
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
```

Faulty attempt to query for `coordinates`:

```java
obj.getJSONArray("features").get(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONArray("coordinates").toString();
```

Warning: `The method getJSONObject(String) is undefined for type object` at `.get(0).getJSONObject("geometry")`

Please advise on how I can query for the `coordinates` array of objects. I'm willing to use different libraries

Comment: You can create POJOs accordingly let it be deserialized by itself.     
`YourPOJO result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, YourPOJO.class);`

Comment: I didn't want to create a custom class due to the deep nesting that would require the creation of 8 classes just to query 1 field but I ended up doing it anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this result sample

```
   {
"type":"FeatureCollection",
"crs":{"type":"link","properties":{"href":"http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/ogcwkt/","type":"ogcwkt"},
"features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPoint","coordinates":[[103.62835,1.29337],[103.63217,1.31944]
......
```

you can loop through result and extract coordinates using JSONArrays & JSONObjects as below

```
JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);

JSONArray featuresArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("features");
System.out.println("\nfeaturesArray = " + featuresArray);
//[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[103.62382,1.28178],[103.6265,1.29515],

for (int f = 0; f < featuresArray.length(); f++) {

    JSONObject featuresObj = featuresArray.getJSONObject(f);
    System.out.println("\nfeaturesObj = " + featuresObj);
    //{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[103.62803,1.28839],[103.62911,1.29983],

    JSONObject geometryObj = featuresObj.getJSONObject("geometry");
    System.out.println("\ngeometryObj = " + geometryObj);
    //{"coordinates":[[103.62711,1.30928],[103.62718,1.29478]

    JSONArray coordsArray = geometryObj.getJSONArray("coordinates");
    System.out.println("\ncoordsArray = " + coordsArray);
    //[[103.61466,1.25029],[103.61822,1.27588],

    for (int c = 0; c < coordsArray.length(); c++) {
        System.out.println("Coord = " + coordsArray.get(c));
        //Coord = [103.62387,1.28607]
        //Coord = [103.62649,1.29515]
    }
}
```